# How to write $y=4x-x^{2}$ as a function with respect to $y$?

Tags: functions

Can someone please help me write $y=4x-x^{2}$ as a function with respect to $y$? I need it to determine the volume of solid of revolution about the $y$ axis.

Comment: For the volume of revolution, it is much easier to use the appropriate ("cylinder"/"shell") volume formula and integrate directly, than to try to invert the function and use the "washer" formula.

Comment: I was given the graph $y = x$ as well to find the volume of revolution around the $y$ axis. I don't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to rotate the area _between_ $y=x$ and $y=4x-x^2$ around the $y$-axis?

Comment: Correct. That is what im looking for.

Comment: x @Aspiring: Then it's still easier to use the "cylinder" formula for the volume between $f$ and $g$, rotated about the vertical axis: $$V=\int_{g(r)\ge f(r)} 2\pi r(g(r)-f(r))\,dr $$

Comment: That method seems complicated to me.

Comment: x @Aspiring: It's much _simpler_ than washers in this case. Otherwise you end up with a piecewise defined upper ("right") bound for the area, square roots all over, and so forth. With cylinders you just have a simple polynomial to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Solve the equation $x^2 - 4x + y = 0$ viewed as a variable of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
this is not a one to one function,
so its not invertible 
but you can obtain inverse in $$[2,\infty)$$ or $$(\infty,+2]$$